# Tabla reinicia ID al eliminar todos los registros

Tags: mysql

Hoy vengo con una duda de algo que nunca me había sucedido, y quizá MySql así lo utilice pero quiero comentarles para ver si a ustedes le ha pasado y si hay manera de resolverlo.
Tengo un pequeño sistema de venta (POS) donde las ventas del día están registradas en la tabla "Venta", y cuando finaliza el turno estas pasan a la tabla HistorialVentas y elimino todos los registros de "Venta" para ser utilizada para el siguiente turno. Esto con la finalidad de que cuando cree algún reporte el sistema cuente sólo con la información de turnos terminados y me descarte las ventas del turno en curso.

El detalle es que, todo funciona perfectamente, ventas, y cierre de turno, los IDs de ventas, los cuales son autoincrementables trabajan bien. Si cierro un turno y al momento continúo con la venta, cero problemas, los IDs continúan la serie, pero, si apago el servidor (PC personal), se va la luz etc, SI la tabla Ventas estaba vacías, los IDs se reinician a 1, lo que provoca claves repetidas.

Si continué al momento con las ventas, la serie la respeta, y así cierre el server etc, contiúa sin problemas. El detalle está cuando la tabla está vacía y se cierra el server, este al volver a abrir, los IDs se reinician a 1.

Es la primera vez que trabajo de esta manera, sé que podría crear consultas que me descarten la venta del día, y busqué ventas de turnos terminados etc. Pero me llama mucho la atención el POR QUÉ MySql reinicia los IDs en lugar de continuar la serie, aun cuando la tabla esté vacía

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que usa InnoDB como motor (engine) de almacenamiento, en la versión 5.7 y anteriores de MySQL, el contador de `AUTO_INCREMENT` se almacena únicamente en memoria y no en disco. Cuando se reinicia el servidor de MySQL, InnoDB ejecuta el equilavente a:

```sql
SELECT MAX(ai_col) FROM table_name FOR UPDATE;
```

Si la tabla no contiene tuplas o registros, básicamente, el contador se inicializará.

Desde la versión 8.0 de MySQL el comportamiento cambió y el contador se almacena en el `redo log` por cada cambio, permitiendo con ello persistir el valor del contador en cada reinico de MySQL.

En la documentación (lamento que sea en inglés) de MySQL se encuentran todos los detalles, si desea ampliar la información, visite: [15.8.1.5 AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

Comment: Excelente dato, sinceramente no tenía conocimiento de ello.
Muchas gracias por la información, me daré una vuelta en el enlace que anexas.
Saludos!!...